# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Xml

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0, system.security

I have class library project in .net standard 2.0.3 where I'm using `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` to sign a xml document with a privateRSAkey.

```
var sign = GetXmlSign(doc, rsa);

private static XmlElement GetXmlSign(XmlDocument xml, AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
{
    var signedXml = new SignedXml(xml) {SigningKey = key};
    var refer = new Reference {Uri = ""};
    reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
    signedXml.AddReference(refer);
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();
    return signedXml.GetXml();
}
```

Now when I'm calling `GetXmlSign(doc, rsa);` I'm getting the exception below.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

## NuGets

[image: Nuget Packages]

Note: There is no Nuget "System.Security.Cryptography.Xml" with Version=4.0.1.0

Comment: I had same issue in .net standard but in .net core it's working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was really simple and stupid..!
I just had to add the same `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` Nuget in my main project where from I calling the library.